# An application of the pigeon hole principle

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

I'm interested in a reference (preferably the original source) of the following result which can be proven using the pigeon hole principle:

Let  $K$ be a subset of $\{1,...,2n\}$ with $|K| \geq n+1$. Then there are $k,l \in K$ such that $k$ is a proper divisor of $l$.

Are there any generalizations?

Comment: Use search engine

Answer (score 3):

I found this [link](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pigeonhole/divide.shtml) from Cut-The-Knot with two references:

1. B. Bollobás, The Art of Mathematics: Coffee Time in Memphis, Cambridge University Press, 2006, p. 48.
2. I. F. Sharygin, Mathematical Mosaic, Mir, 2002, problem 65.3 (in Russian)

Comment: @CopyPastelt Thanks for reference #1 which indicates that the theorem/problem was one of Erdös' favourite problems to test students. The anecdote mentioned in the book must be from around 1960.